# Command line tool to capture webcam video in Windows Xp

Tags: webcam, ffmpeg, video-capture

I want to know how to capture webcam video and dump the raw as well as an encoded version using ffmpeg. I want only the video stream. I'm on Windows xp.

Comment: Are you partial to ffmpeg or are you looking for any command line tool?

Comment: any cmd line tool will do..i think most use ffmpeg somehow..please correct me

Answer (score 10):

From [here](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/DirectShow), you can see a list of DirectShow devices with

```
ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy
```

If you have a built-in webcam on a laptop, it should be called something like `"Integrated Camera", and you can capture from it using the following (obviously, substitute the name of your webcam device, and note that the quotes are required):

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="Integrated Camera" -c copy raw.avi \
-c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -crf 25 encoded.mp4
```

You may be better off using huffyuv instead of raw video - it'll halve your filesize, but be completely lossless. Use `-c:v huffyuv` instead of `-c copy`.

Comment: Just used this to get headshots of someone who stole a number of PCs. Thank you, as this will surely result in an arrest at this point.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you [can](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1726581) do that using VLC, i.e.

```
vlc --dshow-vdev="Monitor Webcam" --dshow-size=640x480 -V dummy 
--intf=dummy --dummy-quiet --video-filter=scene --no-audio 
--scene-path=D:\temp --scene-format=jpeg --scene-prefix=snap 
--scene-replace --run-time=1 --scene-ratio=24 "dshow://" vlc://quit
```

Answer (score 0):

With mplayer/mencoder binary for windows.

Show output from web:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MPlayer for Windows\mplayer.exe" -tv driver=dshow:device=0:adevice=0:audioid=1:input=2 tv://
```

Write output:

```
mencoder.exe -tv driver=dshow:device=0:adevice=0:audioid=1:input=2 tv:// -oac copy -ovc copy -o t.avi
```